# Error from registration server when publishing audio unit

Tags: ios, audiounit, avaudiosession, remoteio

I'm trying to publish an AudioUnit generator on iOS. When I call

```
- (void)publishOutputAudioUnit {

    AudioComponentDescription desc = { kAudioUnitType_RemoteGenerator, 'anap', 'cwcw', 0, 0 };
    OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitPublish(&desc, CFSTR("My app"), 1, m_au);

    if (status) {
        DLog(@"Couldn't publish audio unit");
    }
}
```

I get the console message:

```
ERROR:     [0x39d1518c] 225: error -66748 from registration server
```

with `-66748` as the status. [Google isn't helping me](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Couldn%27t%20publish%20audio%20unit%2066748&oq=Couldn%27t%20publish%20audio%20unit%2066748&aqs=chrome..69i57.7995j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8&rct=j#es_sm=91&q=audiounit%2066748%20error&safe=off) and [neither are the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

I'm getting no other errors setting up my audio session, and using all the latest (iOS 7) AVAudioSession APIs.

Is there some secret I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

What I needed to do was add an entry into the Info.plist:

```
AudioComponents (Array)
     (item 0) (Dictionary)
          version
          manufacturer
          name
          type
          subtype
```

Or, in raw form:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>version</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>manufacturer</key>
        <string>cwcw</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>My amazing app</string>
        <key>type</key>
        <string>aurg</string>
        <key>subtype</key>
        <string>shkr</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also hit the same problem. Even when I had `AudioComponents` in the `Info.plist`, calling `AudioComponentDescription(..)` failed with the same error `-66748 (kAudioComponentErr_NotPermitted)`

Finally, I determined that it's also necessary to have `CFBundleDisplayName` item in the `Info.plist` file.