# Error when trying to use published Inter-App Audio app in Garageband

Tags: ios, audio, ios7, remoteio

My app is registered with the system as providing Inter-App Audio (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145360/error-from-registration-server-when-publishing-audio-unit)). But when I select it in the Garageband Inter-App Audio instrument picker, I get this message in a UIAlertView:

> "App Not Available. The Inter-App Audio app you have selected is not
>   available at this time."

meanwhile, in the console, I get this:

```
ERROR:     [0x241000] >aurioc> 783: failed: '!int' (enable 3, outf< 2 ch,  44100 Hz, Int8.24, non-inter> inf< 2 ch,  44100 Hz, Int8.24, non-inter>)
```

Anyone? Someone's aurio is angry... potentially because of a format incompatibility?

Comment: Note to moderators: I'd love an "inter-app-audio" tag, but I don't quite have the rep to make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!int` is an error code, defined in `AVAudioSession.h` under the constant `AVAudioSessionErrorCodeCannotInterruptOthers`. It means that an attempt was made to make a nonmixable audio session active while the app was in the background.

Basically, you disallowed your app from mixing it's audio with other apps, which is needed for inter app audio nodes.